# STM32F401 USB D+ Pull Up

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-device, stm32f4

I am using an STM32F401 microprocessor
I understand that for a regular STM32F4 I don't need a pull-up for USB

However I don't know what happens for the case of OTG
Do I need a pull up on the D+ line for OTG? Can I make this switchable?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to better reflect what you need help with. As it stands, it is difficult to understand, particularly the last sentence (the use of "tune" is almost certainly incorrect).

Comment: @uint128_t I edited the question

Comment: What do you want to do I mean this "D+ signal" seems to be a part of a larger goal. Please add some reference what signaling do you want to do.

Comment: I mean USB_FS_DP http://image.prntscr.com/image/3a43f2833e7a414ca2931585af0090bf.png

Comment: I want to pull him out without using a resistor.